# Calculate rotation matrix offset

Tags: opengl, matrix, lwjgl, rotational-matrices

we are working on a virtual reality environment with a HMD and have continous tracker data coming as quaternions. We calculate a roatation Matrix from that and let OpenGL do the rest.

Now we want to set a certain direction in the beginning, meaning to reset the data coming from the tracker and always calculate an Offset.

Edit: 
After some more testing we figured the following is correct as we switch from a left handed to a right handed coordinate system by changing axisin the calculation and the soure.

```
public void trackerPositionUpdate(TrackerUpdate u, TrackerRemote tracker) {

    if (!isreset){

        //Set reference reset-viewpoint here
        Matrix4f.setIdentity(reset);
        reset.m00=1;
        reset.m11=-1;
        reset.m22=1;

        //get quaternion
        float qx = (float)u.quat[0];
        float qy = (float)u.quat[1];
        float qz = (float)u.quat[2];
        float qw = (float)u.quat[3];

        //quaternion to rotation matrix for reset reasons - axis 2 and 3 switched
        orientation.m00 = 1.0f - (2.0f*(qy*qy) + 2.0f*(qz*qz));
        orientation.m02 = 2.0f*qx*qy - 2.0f*qz*qw;
        orientation.m01 = 2.0f*qx*qz + 2.0f*qy*qw;
        orientation.m03 = 0.0f;

        orientation.m10 = 2.0f*qx*qy + 2.0f*qz*qw;
        orientation.m12 = 1.0f - (2.0f*qx*qx + 2.0f*qz*qz);
        orientation.m11 = 2.0f*qy*qz - 2.0f*qx*qw;
        orientation.m13 = 0.0f;

        orientation.m20 = 2.0f*qx*qz - 2.0f*qy*qw;
        orientation.m22 = 2.0f*qy*qz + 2.0f*qx*qw;
        orientation.m21 = 1.0f - (2.0f*qx*qx + 2.0f*qy*qy);
        orientation.m23 = 0.0f;

        orientation.m30 = 0.0f;
        orientation.m32 = 0.0f;
        orientation.m31 = 0.0f;
        orientation.m33 = 1.0f;


        //this inverts the elevation and needs to be set for the tracker to work correctly with the audio coordinate system
        orientation.m01 *= -1 ;
        orientation.m11 *= -1 ;
        orientation.m21 *= -1 ;
        orientation.m31 *= -1 ;

        //invert matrix
        orientation.invert();

        //Mreset = Mdest * Morientation^(-1)
        Matrix4f.mul(reset, orientation, reset);
        isreset=true;
        System.out.println("Ivas_VRPNTracker# bool isreset: " + isreset);
    }


    // Get quaternion from trackerinput
    float qx = (float)u.quat[0];
    float qy = (float)u.quat[1];
    float qz = (float)u.quat[2];
    float qw = (float)u.quat[3];


    //original :x = 0,y = 1 , z = 2;
    Tracker_X         = u.pos[0];
    Tracker_Y         = u.pos[2];
    Tracker_Z         = -u.pos[1];

    //1st row
    orientation.m00 = 1.0f - (2.0f*(qy*qy) + 2.0f*(qz*qz));
    orientation.m02 = 2.0f*qx*qy - 2.0f*qz*qw;
    orientation.m01 = 2.0f*qx*qz + 2.0f*qy*qw;
    orientation.m03 = 0.0f;

    //2nd row
    orientation.m10 = 2.0f*qx*qy + 2.0f*qz*qw;
    orientation.m12 = 1.0f - (2.0f*qx*qx + 2.0f*qz*qz);
    orientation.m11 = 2.0f*qy*qz - 2.0f*qx*qw;
    orientation.m13 = 0.0f;

    //3rd row
    orientation.m20 = 2.0f*qx*qz - 2.0f*qy*qw;
    orientation.m22 = 2.0f*qy*qz + 2.0f*qx*qw;
    orientation.m21 = 1.0f - (2.0f*qx*qx + 2.0f*qy*qy);
    orientation.m23 = 0.0f;

    //4th row
    orientation.m30 = 0.0f;
    orientation.m32 = 0.0f;
    orientation.m31 = 0.0f;
    orientation.m33 = 1.0f;


    //this inverts the elevation and needs to be set for the tracker to work correctly with the audio coordinate system
    orientation.m01 *= -1 ;
    orientation.m11 *= -1 ;
    orientation.m21 *= -1 ;
    orientation.m31 *= -1 ;


    //define reset by multiplication with rotational reset matrix
    //Mview = Morientationcurrent * Mreset
    Matrix4f.mul(orientation,reset, orientation);
```

We then multiply the orientation matrix with the model view matrix. **This works fine, but we have trouble finding a routine to reset the position when pressing enter.**

Comment: When you say that the position is correct, but a "certain axis" is negated, is it consistently a single axis? It sounds like you're dealing with right-handed vs. left-handed coordinate systems.

Comment: When we do tracking without the oriention reset (Offset) the tracking orientation is correct. In my understanding we switched to axis in the Rotation Matrix (2 columns in calculation). That works fine for just the tracking but seems to cause Problems when trying to reset. unfortunately i cannot test any solutions until next week.